# See UDF Argument Descriptions in Other Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

1. Create a UDF.
2. Use [this site](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/user-defined_function_argument_descriptions_in_excel_2010/) to create function and argument descriptions.
3. Use UDF, open function wizard, all descriptions are displayed. Great!
4. Go to another workbook while this is still open.
5. Use UDF from initial workbook (with the necessary prefix), open function wizard, only the function description is displayed (no argument descriptions). Boo!

Is there a way to have the argument descriptions display in #5?

Adding function and argument descriptions for a UDF appears to be brand new to Excel 2010, so I suspect this may simply be not currently possible, but I cannot actually find the idea of using it in other workbooks discussed, and haven't been able to get it to work myself. Descriptive variable names can only get you so far, and function descriptions are limited to 255 characters (at least that's the largest using the link's method).

It would be ideal to have this work using the built-in function wizard so it can be accessed outside a macro, but these functions are often created using macros, so if you have a particularly good alternate suggestion, that would be appreciated as well.

Excel 2010, Windows 7 Professional

Comment: From Workbook2, you want to use a UDF stored in Workbook1 and have all the descriptions carry over?

Comment: @vsoraas Yup. In the second, the UDFs from the first work fine, and the function description displays, just the argument descriptions don't. Slightly edited to hopefully make that clearer for future people.

Comment: Did you try running the `DescribeFunction()` in the new workbook?

Comment: @paul bica This is not reasonable due to these functions being constantly used in new workbooks throughout my company. My current workaround of doing my best to describe everything in the 255 character function description is preferable to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works Ok if you put the UDF and DESCRIBEFUNCTION in an XLAM and open that before opening another workbook.
But note that you cannot run DESCRIBEFUNCTION in the workbook open event of the XLAM if it is opened before any other workbooks.

Comment: I was going to suggest the PERSONAL.xlsb, but I'm not sure how it can be loaded permanently

Comment: Thank you for your advice - when I have time I will have to look into XLAM and how it is different from what we currently do, which is have a xlsm file in the xlstart folder that opens hidden automatically.

Comment: Huh... well that was oddly easy. Still curious why the other method makes the overall description transfer ok and not the argument descriptions, but this does appear to sufficiently resolve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand... while shortcuts and ribbon buttons work, the add-in macros do not show up when you choose Macros in the Developer tab???

Comment: Alright, as per http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/410251-add-not-showing-macros-list.html and http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/cannot-display-add-in-macro-list-without-going-to-vba-project.4039730/ it seems I cannot have macros from an add-in show up with the macro button. So the best solution seems to be to use an add-in for the functions and a hidden auto-opening workbook for the macros.